# How can I force pyspark code to run after a function

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to be able to force spark to execute my code in the order I want.

In the example below, `foo` and `bar` functions does data manipulation but `send_request` is just a web trigger unaffected by those functions. When Spark executes below code it runs the `send_request` the first and `foo` and `bar` later.

It does not work for me because after `foo` and `bar` completed, I have timeout from my request. If the request ran after `foo`, the result would be ready at the same time `bar` ends. 
How could I achieve this in spark.

I could have separate scripts for each step but cluster starting times adds up hence I would like to be able modify execution order. 
I am using databricks on Azure if it helps.

```
import os
import base64
import requests
import pyspark

sc.addFile("dbfs:/bar.py")
from bar import bar 

sc.addFile("dbfs:/foo.py")
from foo import foo

if __name__ == '__main__':

    foo()
    response = send_request(request=request_json)
    bar()
```

the content of `foo` and `bar` and `send_request` are as follows

```
def foo():
    df = spark.read.parquet(file_1_path)
    df = df.filter(F.col('IDType') == 'E') \
      .select(F.col('col1'),F.col('col2')).distinct()
    df.repartition(10).write.parquet(file_1_new_path)
    logger.info('1 foo is done')
```

and

```
def bar():
    df = spark.read.parquet(file_2_path)
    df = df.filter(F.col('IDType') == 'M') \
      .select(F.col('col1'),F.col('col2')).distinct()
    df.repartition(10).write.parquet(file_2_new_path)
    logger.info('3 bar is done')
```

and

```
def send_request():
    response_json = http_response.json()
    logger.info('2 request is sent')
```

I will try to be more clear. When I run above code in spark the output I get is as follows

```
 2 request is sent
 1 foo is done
 3 bar is done
```

But I want it to be in this order

```
 1 foo is done
 2 request is sent
 3 bar is done
```

Comment: This does not show us any spark-related problem. You may need to add the spark code in `foo()` and `bar()` to clarify your question.

Comment: edited the question with 'foo' and 'bar' info.

Comment: Is `send_request()` asynchronous?